# Read file without disk caching in Linux

Tags: linux, io

I have a C program that runs only weekly, and reads a large amount of files **only once**. Since Linux also caches everything that's read, they fill up the cache needlessly and this slows down the system a lot unless it has an SSD drive.

So how do I open and read from a file without filling up the disk cache?

**Note:**

By disk caching I mean that when you read a file twice, the second time it's read from RAM, not from disk. I.e. data once read from the disk is left in RAM, so subsequent reads of the same file will not need to reread the data from disk.

Comment: You'd think Linux would have some configuration regarding disk caching. Either way, is this really a C problem? You would have the same problem regardless of the programming language, wouldn't you? Have you tried running the program in valgrind? It could be that you have memory leaks.

Comment: That's true, but otherwise someone might have posted python code samples :)

Comment: Well, if you hadn't asked for C you would've got more "Linux" answers. Please answer all of my questions: Have you tried running your program in valgrind?

Comment: OK, I removed the C tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`posix_fadvise()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) with the `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` advice to request that the system free the pages you've already read.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE be more appropriate? Just looked at the link.

Comment: It probably would, but the documentation suggests it is a no-op.

Comment: I would prefer using fadvise as opposed to O_DIRECT. You can even have another program periodically telling system that it doesn't need to cache certain files. I had it like that when parsing large logfiles with awstats.

Comment: You can use POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE _before_ reading the data and POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED _after_ reading.

POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE is currently a no-op, but maybe it will be implemented someday.

Comment: As suggested in https://github.com/jborg/attic/issues/252, the current implementation in Linux will unconditionally purge cached pages, possibly degrading the performance of other applications using the same files.

Answer (score 10):

I believe passing `O_DIRECT` to [`open()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) should help:

> **O_DIRECT (Since Linux 2.4.10)**
>
> Try to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from this file. In general this will degrade performance, but it is useful in special situations, such as when applications do their own caching. File I/O is done directly to/from user space buffers. The O_DIRECT flag on its own makes at an effort to transfer data synchronously, but does not give the guarantees of the O_SYNC that data and necessary metadata are transferred. To guarantee synchronous I/O the O_SYNC must be used in addition to O_DIRECT.

There are further detailed notes on `O_DIRECT` towards the bottom of the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open), including a fun quote from Linus.

Comment: Just to be sure, since it says "In general this will degrade performance" - it won't actually degrade it for me, right? Because I really am reading the files only once.

Comment: @sashoalm: I think that's exactly what it means. It'll degrade the performance of repeated reads. However, since you're not doing repeated reads, this won't apply to you. If anything, it should improve performance in your case, since you won't be needlessly polluting the cache.

Comment: IIRC, this will disable read ahead, which is likely where the performance degradation comes in

Comment: Indeed. No caching means if you were to read char by char, then the drive would be seeking once for each char rather than seeking once for 4KB, which is 4096 times more seeking. I don't think this is what the OP wants.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: That's not quite true: you wouldn't even be able to read one char using `O_DIRECT`. This is covered in detail in the man page I've linked to. To give just one quote: *Under Linux 2.4, transfer sizes, and the alignment of the user buffer and the file offset must all be multiples of the logical block size of the file system. Under Linux 2.6, alignment to 512-byte boundaries suffices.*

Comment: Note that using `O_DIRECT` will reduce performance if same files are read with other processes without `O_DIRECT` flag. In that case, both readers suffer a performance penalty. If you truly know that no other process is reading those files and you only need to read the files once, `O_DIRECT` may be a good solution.