# kernel is not clearing the cache memory on memory depletion

Tags: caching, memory-management, linux-kernel, out-of-memory

Am using linux-2.6.32 and found strange behavior that kernel is unable to relinquish the cache memory on memory depletion.When it happens system will go for reboot. To alleviate the problem I clear cache memory using echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches.

My question is why kernel is unable to clear the cache memory on memory depletion ?

Comment: Kernel is able. Read comments to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53936183/linux-disk-cache-and-kmalloc-with-gfp-atomic)

Comment: Also look at [this](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/tuning-kernel-memory-for-performance/4195/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot redOct. I will try the /proc settings mentioned in above posts.